# How do I animate text links using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am somewhat new to jQuery and I have a problem with something I am trying to implement.

I have a vertical navigation menu where each link animates on hover by changing color, increasing letter spacing, and adding a border on the left.

Everything is working the way I want it to except for when I click on the link. After I click on the link, the text changes to a different color and remains that same color even when I hover over the link.

I am wanting to make it to where the color change on hover remains intact even after I click the link.
I'm sure I am missing something simple, but I have tried everything I know to do with no luck.
Any suggestions would be helpful!

Here is what I have for the animation...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.navlist li a").hover(function(){
       $(this).stop()
          .animate({paddingLeft: '10px',letterSpacing: '2px',borderWidth:'20px'},
                       {queue:false,easing:'easeInQuad'},50)
    },
    function(){
       $(this).stop()
           .animate({paddingLeft: '0px', letterSpacing: '0px',borderWidth:'0px'},
                    {queue:false,easing:'easeOutQuad'},50)
    });
});

</script>
```

My css for the navigation list is here...

```
.navlist {
    list-style: none;
}


.navlist a {
    border-left-color: #555555;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    color: #c4c4c4;
}

.navlist a:hover {
    border-left-color: #555555;
    border-left-style: solid;
    color: #555555;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `.navlist a:visited` declaration between `.navlist a` and `.navlist a:hover` that sets the text color to #c4c4c4.

Comment: You may also need to change `.navlist a:hover` to `.navlist a:hover, .navlist a:hover:visited` so that the hover color will always work regardless of whether the link was visited or not...that may not be the case though.

Comment: You don't need another declaration, just change `.navlist a {` to `.navlist a, .navlist a:visited {`

Comment: @Pickle I had tried adding the color to .navlist a:visited but it didn't work the way I wanted it to. It changed the visited link to the right color off-hover but when I hovered over the link after it had been clicked, the hover color would not show up anymore.

Comment: @Matt Huggins Adding .navlist a:hover:visited worked perfectly! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Peter - don't forget to rate answers and comments up if they helped you, so that others with the same question will know what pieces of info are useful.  Also, be sure to click the checkmark on Pickle's answer if it worked for you!